# Selecting a Random Sample from a View in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have generated a view from a table in PostgreSQL consisting of 50,000 rows. I want to take a random sample from this view based on a number of conditions. I understand this can be done in the following way:

```
select * from viewname
where columnname = 'A'  -- the condition
order by columnname 
limit 5;
```

However, instead of 'limit 5', I want to take a percentage of the number of rows which meet this condition. So for instance, 'limit 5%' (though this is not correct syntax). I understand a similar thing can be done with the tablesample clause but this does not apply to views.

Comment: The standard way to sample is `order by random()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the window function PERCENT_RANK

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  select *, PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY columnname ORDER BY random()) AS pcrnk
  from tablename
  where columnname = 'A'
) q
WHERE pcrnk <= 0.05
```

And if you don't want to see that pcrnk in the result?

```
SELECT (t).*
FROM 
(
  select t, PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY columnname ORDER BY random()) AS pcrnk
  from tablename t
  where columnname = 'A'
) q
WHERE pcrnk <= 0.05
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=64fe11cfd0d039232d8ef4587c67406b)*

These queries will retrieve 5% of what be retrieved normally based on the criteria `columnname = 'A'`
F.e. if there are 100 'A' and 1000 'B', then they return 5 records.

If you want to return 5% of all the records in the table?  Then here's another trick.

```
select *
from tablename
where columnname = 'A'
order by random()
limit 0.05 * (select count(*) from tablename)
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thanks so much! A final thing - I aim to take a percentage of rows that meet different conditions, such as `where columnname = 'B'`, and so on. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this or would I have to create different select statements each time?

Comment: @EarlofMar Not sure what you mean.  Something like columnname equals 'A' or 'B'?  Then just change the WHERE clause as in `WHERE columnname IN ('A','B')`. Then because of the PARTITION on columnname you get 5% of 'A' plus 5% of 'B'.  If you want 5% of all, just remove the PARTITION.

Comment: Apologies, should have been clearer. So I want to take different percentages of 'A', 'B' and so on and wondered if I could do this without writing out the select statement each time. For instance, I first want to take 5% of 'A' and then 10% of 'B', and so on.

Comment: @EarlofMar Well, that seems easy to do in the WHERE clause of the outer query q. `WHERE ((columnname = 'A' AND pcrnk <= 0.05) OR (columnname = 'B' AND pcrnk <= 0.10))`.  Because pcrnk is partitioned by columnname you get a different pcrnk count per columnname .

Comment: @EarlofMar Test *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1f2791411a4b928605db4d2ce380ee39)*

Comment: Phenomenal. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to randomly select a percentage of your rows, and if you have Postgres 9.5 or higher, have a look at Postgres [TABLESAMPLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).

It has two options : `BERNOULLI` and `SYSTEM` :

> The BERNOULLI and SYSTEM sampling methods each accept a single argument which is the fraction of the table to sample, expressed as a percentage between 0 and 100. [...] These two methods each return a randomly-chosen sample of the table that will contain approximately the specified percentage of the table's rows.

`SYSTEM` is faster, but `BERNOULLI` gives better random distribution because each record has the same probability on being selected.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(5)
WHERE columnname = 'A'  -- the condition
ORDER BY columnname;
```

NB : this only works if you are querying a table, and not for views.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't support views.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : ahh, ok, I see... Thanks for checking, I am deleting my answer because it does not properly responds to the question.

Comment: Don't delete it. It's still a valuable answer. Just add a remark. At first this question didn't use viewname but tablename.

Comment: The documentation for TABLESAMPLE says "This sampling precedes the application of any other filters such as WHERE clauses."  So in the example given above, 5% of the rows are filtered for "columnname = 'A'".  It that's a rare condition, you might end up with few or even no records.